# Disable "getPropertyName" method mapping to property for mapster

Tags: c#, mapster

Suppose I have two classes and use [Mapster](https://github.com/eswann/Mapster) to map one to another:

```
class A 
{
   public int GetX(){ return 1; }
}

class B 
{
   public int X { get; set; }
}
```

Is any way to globally disable map of `GetX()` to `X` for `A` to `B` mapping?
This behavior is by default, it is described [here](https://github.com/eswann/Mapster#ConversionPOCO), but I've not found any way to change it.

Comment: A curious case: the mapper tries to map `GetType` method, which is of every object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like accurately described [here](https://github.com/eswann/Mapster/issues/91), mapping strategy can be easily changed with

```
  TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.Default.Settings.ValueAccessingStrategies
                .Remove(ValueAccessingStrategy.GetMethod);
```